# GCP tag Binding - Error while listing or creating

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using GCP command line to list TAG binding and create new TAG binding. However, I am getting following error.

command

```
gcloud beta resource-manager tags  bindings list --parent=projects/xxxx --location=northamerica-northeast1
```

**Error**

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.resource-manager.tags.bindings.list) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: Must be a valid One Platform resource name of a tag compatible regional
      resource
    field: binding.resource
  - description: Resource type not supported in location northamerica-northeast1
    field: binding.resource
```

same error when I am trying to create a new binding

```
gcloud resource-manager tags bindings create --tag-value=tagValues/xxx --parent=//cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/xxx/locations/northamerica-northeast1/functions/function-1-test --location=northamerica-northeast
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a 3rd-party [documentation](https://www.cloudbolt.io/gcp-cost-optimization/gcp-tags/) discussing how to create tag binding in a different method.